# Is there an idiomatic way to get a potentially undefined key from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, idioms

PHPeoples, I'm so tired of doing this

```
$value = isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : null;
```

Or this

```
$value = array_key_exists($key, $arr) ? $arr[$key] : null;
```

---

Don't nobody tell me to do

```
$arr   = array(1);
$key   = 5;
$value = $arr[$key];
// Notice: Undefined offset: 5
```

I got bronchitis. Ain't nobody got time f'dat.

---

I could make a function, I guess...

```
function array_get(Array $arr, $key, $default=null) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $arr)
    ? $arr[$key]
    : $default
  ;
}
```

But is this the best (most idiomatic) way?

Comment: This is reasonable to me. I use the same trick to get $_POST or $_GET params, with a default value. Your question was better before you added all the gimmicks.

Comment: Yea, a function call and 2 required params would be the minimal.

Comment: Who down-votes this without a comment? RIP

Comment: you're not going to save any time/space with the "functioned" version.

Comment: @MarcB, I think `$val = array_get($arr, $key);` reads way nicer than `$val = isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : null;`. I think it saves time/space and everything in between too.

Comment: Try `filter_input()`.  Does what is reqiured, but wait there's more!

Comment: @AbraCadaver, thanks for the suggestion, but this generic question has nothing to do with `$_GET`, `$_POST`, et al. specifically.

Comment: In that case @Jasper "_Interesting, when would you not know what keys you need for a piece of code?_"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More elegant way of doing it:

```
function ifsetor(&$value, $default = null) {
    return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
$value   = ifsetor($arr[$key]);
$message = ifsetor($_POST['message'], 'No message posted');
```

etc. Here `$value` is passed by reference, so it wouldn't throw a Notice.

Further reading:

- [NikiC's blog — The case against the ifsetor function](http://nikic.github.io/2014/01/10/The-case-against-the-ifsetor-function.html)
- PHP RFC — https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make sure certain keys exist then you can create a default array and merge in your input (or whatever). That way all necessary keys will exist and they will be updated if possible:

```
$defaults = array(
    'foo' => '',
    'bar' => ''
);

$data = array_merge($defaults, $someOtherArray);
```

Docs for `array_merge()`: http://php.net/array_merge

I find this helpful when taking into consideration check-boxes on a HTML form that may or may not show up in `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Note that this process expects string array keys, not numeric ones. See the documentation for clarification.

Comment: I'm familiar with this technique, and OK, this is fine for an assoc array that has defaults, but there's not always defaults to be defined. This solution isn't applicable for my `$val = $arr[5]` example.

Comment: @naomik Interesting, when would you not know what keys you need for a piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the function **isset()** does not return TRUE for array keys that correspond to a **NULL** value, while **array_key_exists()** does. So all above answer don't correct work with **NULL** element in array. You can check my edit answer for this situation. For example we had some array:

```
   $test = array(NULL,'',0,false,'0');
```

If we use (from answer above in this topic) function:

```
function ifsetor(&$value, $default = null) {
    return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}
```

and try to get array data:

```
echo '---------------------';
var_dump($test);
echo 'Array count : '.count($test).'<br>';
echo '---------------------';
var_dump(ifsetor($test[0], 'Key not exists'));
var_dump(ifsetor($test[1],'Key not exists'));
var_dump(ifsetor($test[2],'Key not exists'));
var_dump(ifsetor($test[3], 'Key not exists'));
var_dump(ifsetor($test[4],'Key not exists'));
var_dump(ifsetor($test1[5],'Key not exists'));

function ifsetor(&$value, $default = null) {
    return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}
```

our result be:

```
---------------------

array (size=5)
  0 => null
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => int 0
  3 => boolean false
  4 => string '0' (length=1)

Array count : 5
---------------------

string 'Key not exists' (length=9) //But value in this key of array - NULL! and key exists

string '' (length=0)

int 0

boolean false

string '0' (length=1)

string 'Key not exists' (length=9)
```

So we can check it use **isset** and **array_key_exists** together. Don't forget check this is array or not;

```
echo '---------------------';
var_dump($test);
echo 'Array count : '.count($test).'<br>';
echo '---------------------';
var_dump(array_get($test, 0, 'Key not exists'));
var_dump(array_get($test, 1,'Key not exists'));
var_dump(array_get($test, 2,'Key not exists'));
var_dump(array_get($test, 3, 'Key not exists'));
var_dump(array_get($test, 4,'Key not exists'));
var_dump(array_get($test, 5,'Key not exists')); //Key not exists
var_dump(array_get($test1, 5,'Key not exists')); //This is not array


function array_get($arr, $key, $default=null) {
  if(is_array($arr)){
    return  isset($arr[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $arr)
        ? $arr[$key]
        : $default;
  }else{
    return 'No array given';
  }

}
```

Now the answer is correct:

```
---------------------

array (size=5)
  0 => null
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => int 0
  3 => boolean false
  4 => string '0' (length=1)

Array count : 5
---------------------

null  //Perfect - key exists!

string '' (length=0)

int 0

boolean false

string '0' (length=1)

string 'No array given' (length=14)

string 'Key not exists' (length=14)
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote this, but you need to use `return isset($value) ?...` instead of `return $value ?...`

Comment: @naomik Why we need use **isset**? Please explain? We use '?' - The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE

Comment: if `$value` evaluated to a "falsey" value (`0`, `false`, `''`), your function would return `null`.

Comment: I edit my answer and add check key for array and NULL value. Please check and answer for my solution)

Answer (score 0):

It's already a built-in function if using `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV`, you can use:

```
$value = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $key);
```

Plus it does much more. Optional filters make it handy if you also want validate or sanitize filters in the same assignment.

> Returns - Value of the requested variable on success, FALSE if the filter fails,
>   or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set. If the flag
>   FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is used, it returns FALSE if the variable is
>   not set and NULL if the filter fails.